# Shell script for getting limited Values from Delimited Values

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I need a shell script for the below.

I have 14 variables as:

scenario 1
input:

```
a#@#b#@#c#@#d#@#e#@#f#@#g#@#e#@#f#@#g#@#h#@#i#@#j#@#k#@#l#@#m#@#n
```

scenario 2
input:

```
a#@#b#@#c#@#d#@#e#@#f#@#g#@#e#@#f#@#g#@#h#@#i#@#j#@#k#@#l#@#m#@#n#@#
```

I want output as

```
op1 = a

op2 = b

op3 = c

op4 = d

op5 = e

op6 = g

op7 = f

op8 = h

op9 = i

op10 = j

op11 = k

op12 = l

op13 = m

op14 = n
```

Here `op1` to `op14` are variable in which i have to store the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First replace `#@#` with a single, unique character delimiter e.g. `#`, then use `read` to read it into an array. The elements of the array contain the characters. This is shown below.

```
$ input="a#@#b#@#c#@#d#@#e#@#f#@#g#@#e#@#f#@#g#@#h#@#i#@#j#@#k"
$ IFS='#' read -a arr  <<< "${input//#@#/#}"
$ echo ${arr[0]}
a
$ echo ${arr[1]}
b
$ echo ${arr[13]}
k

# print out the whole array
$ for (( i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i++ ))
> do
>     echo "Element at index $i is ${arr[i]}"
> done
Element at index 0 is a
Element at index 1 is b
Element at index 2 is c
Element at index 3 is d
Element at index 4 is e
Element at index 5 is f
Element at index 6 is g
Element at index 7 is e
Element at index 8 is f
Element at index 9 is g
Element at index 10 is h
Element at index 11 is i
Element at index 12 is j
Element at index 13 is k
```

Comment: IFS is the Internal Field Separator that is used to split lines into words with the `read` builtin command.

Comment: can you please explain this part `read -a arr  <<< "${input//#@#/#}"`

Comment: `${input//#@#/#}` replaces `#@#` with `#` in the input string. The result is passed to the `read` command which stores it into an array variable called `arr`.